# How can I get PostgreSQL to follow up filtering jobs that my FDW ignored?

Tags: postgresql, windows, visual-studio, c

I'm making a FDW (Foreign Data Wrapper) in PostgreSQL for myself using C.
It seems to be working rudimentary, but I have one problem.

When I pass it a query like the following via psql:

```
select * from FOREIGN_TABLE_A where COL1=1 and COL2=1;
```

...then the FDW ignores the second search predicate `(COL2=1)`.

How can I make PostgreSQL use my second search predicate?

I tried debugging but PostgreSQL never returned any useful results.

Are there any rules for enabling PostgreSQL to use multiple predicates in a FDW in `GetForeignRelSize()`, `GetForeignPaths()` or `GetForeignPlan()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is up to your foreign data wrapper to push down all `WHERE` conditions.

The `WHERE` conditions are passed as part of `RelOptInfo *baserel` to `GetForeignRelSize` and `GetForeignPaths`.  `baserel->baserestrictinfo` is a `List *` of `RestrictInfo *`. It seems that your code only uses the first element of that list.

Comment: Thank you for your help Laurenz, Is there any way to deny a part of pushing down of the WHERE conditions selectively? and Is there any documents to know how to use the Restrictinfo? Best regards. yasoo7964

Comment: Ive found a way myself to deny / allow pushing down by tweaking the classifyConditions() in deparse.c @postgres_fdw. so now i can ignore the part of WHERE condisions selectively, its fullfill my purpose. By the way, is it possible are there any way to make PostgreSQL follow up my omitted WHERE clause which was pushed down and ignored by FDW?

Comment: Yes, you have to let PostgreSQL evaluate the conditions you don't push down. If you are modifying postgres_fdw, it is all there. The documentation is in the comments.

Comment: Thank you, Ill try looking into postgres_fdw.